# Need to simplify this long javascript line

Tags: javascript

You can see that the below function contain a long line of code...
I want to simplify this...
One idea would be to use multiple variable but I don't want to do so...

Any idea on how can I simplify this?

```
function updateStatusBar() {
  var text = textarea.value;
  statusBar.value = "Words: " + (text.split(/\b\S+\b/g).length - 1) + "  Characters: " + text.replace(/\n|[" "]/g, "").length + " / " + text.replace(/\n/g, "").length;
}
```

Comment: This question is probably more suitable for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: I think the line is doing what it have to do as shorter as possible...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3):

You can use other functions to break down functionality:

```
function updateStatusBar() {
    var text = textarea.value;
    statusBar.value = "Words: " +  getWordCount(text) + "  Characters: " + getCharCount(text);
}

function getWordCount(text) {
    return (text.split(/\b\S+\b/g).length - 1);
}

function getCharCount(text) {
    return text.replace(/\n|[" "]/g, "").length + " / " + text.replace(/\n/g, "").length;
}
```